# Trying to setup a NumberPicker to show value in Toast

Tags: java, android, android-number-picker

I'm using the **NumberPicker** tool in Android and I changed the value of the integer to String to be able to show it in the Toast I used `Integer.toString` method but I don't think the problem is that.

The thing is when I tap my button no matter what value I pick in the **NumberPicker** it shows **(0)**. I'm using the `.getValue();` as shown below.

How do I make it get the value that I set on **NumberPicker**?

```
numPickerMin = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMinute);

//Min
numPickerMin.setMaxValue(60);
numPickerMin.setMinValue(0);
numPickerMin.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();
final String getValMin= Integer.toString(getvalueminute);

silentButton.setOnClickListener(
  new Button.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v){
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,getValMin,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting Picker's value after you initialize it so it will always be 0. As I understand your code you want to show correct value in Toast after pressing button? You should move those lines inside OnClickListener:

`int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();
String getValMin= Integer.toString(getvalueminute);`

Comment: Correct that's what I want to do. And what you suggested did not work.

Comment: Got it. Thank you generous stranger.